# Is it ok to expose API keys in frontend code if the site is behind a login?

Tags: reactjs, api, gitlab, api-key, gitlab-pages

I'm trying to develop a simple internal site for home use in React (using Vite). The only users will be members of my household and never anyone else.

For this project I decided to go with GitLab Pages as it allows me to make a private pages site (behind login) for free vs other providers (e.g. Netlify which requires you to pay for password protection).

Yesterday I added a call to a weather API so that I can add weather data to this site. The API requires an API Key and for starters I have this within the frontend code. I wnet down the rabbit hole of not having API Keys visible in my frontend code only to realize that I'd need some sort of backend service to really hide these keys.

As this is a simple internal home only project - I'm wondering if it's ok just to leave the keys in the frontend code as the site is behind a login anyway? Later I plan on adding some more private API keys (some basic budgeting information which I will get from my budgeting app's API).

Comment: Since you seem to have a login system, why you don't make the call to the weather API from your back end and send the information back to your logged in user?

Comment: I don't have a backend per se, just using GitLab's private pages which can only be accessed if you can access my project

Answer (score 1):

The answer simply is NO. You must not reveal your secrets on the client side of your applications unless you can protect them from your API or service provider by whitelisting your website and preventing other origins from using your keys.

If someone discovers them, they will be able to use your quotas and that may lead to blocking your requests if the limited number of calls per time unit is achieved.

I can recommend using serverless functions for your case. They're free as long as you do not exceed the compute limit.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a simple way to implement a serverless function? I'm not a pro developer by any means, so would like a somewhat easy approach